# How to add support for larger android screens (21:9)?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, screen, display

I found an open source app that doesn't scale up on my big screen of aspect ratio (21:9) and it just stays (16:9) size. So my question is how do I can support bigger screens?

I've really tried to find an answer on Google but I'm a beginner and I couldn't really find a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach to this is using consrait layout and using match constraints easily.

However, for a simpler solution, you can use this library

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
 implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

This library uses scalable dp for the design once and adjust to the screensize automatically

[Sdp library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)